# "TypeError: User.serializeUser is not a function" with passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, passport-local

I am new to passport JS , and i was making my first program in passport, i had app.js in my main directory and user.js in the models directory inside the main directory. 
When i tried to run the command **node app.js** i recieved the following error.

```
C:\Users\RAJ\Desktop\webD\auth\app.js:26
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser()); //encrypt
                            ^

TypeError: User.serializeUser is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\RAJ\Desktop\webD\auth\app.js:26:29)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:193:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:617:3
```

Following is my two files app.js and user.js.

> app.js

```
var express               = require('express'),
mongoose              = require('mongoose'),
bodyParser            = require('body-parser'),
passport              = require('passport'),
User                  = require('./models/user'),
localStrategy         = require('passport-local'),
passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/auth_demo");

 var app = express();
 app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.get("/",function(req,res){
res.render("home");
});
app.use(require("express-session")({
     secret : "some random shit",
     resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
//setting up passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser()); //encrypt
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser()); //decrypt
app.get("/secret",function(req,res)
{
  res.render("secret");
});
 app.get("/register",function(req,res)
 {
    res.render("register");
 });
app.listen(8000,function(){
    console.log("server has started running");
});
```

> user.js

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.export = mongoose.model("User",UserSchema);
```

> Below is the list dependencies in package.json that I installed.

```
 "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "ejs": "^2.5.7",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.8",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-local-mongoose": "^5.0.0"
  }
```

Comment: i got the error. module.exports will fix it, earlier i wrote module.export, it was a typoi got the error. module.exports will fix it, earlier i wrote module.export, it was a typo

Answer (score 5):

The export module is wrong is:

Is not module.export

```
module.export = mongoose.model("User",UserSchema);
```

but is module.exports

```
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to build your own serializeuser() and deserializeUser() functions.

**serializeUser** is used to store id of the user in the session,while **deserializeUser** is used to retrieve the user details of the user by fetching the id from the session and then fetching the whole user details from your database. Example:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(req, user, done) {
    done(null, user.user_id);
});



passport.deserializeUser(function(user_id, done) {
    getUserInfo(user_id).then(function(user) {
        return done(null, user);
    }, function(err) {
        return done(err,null);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this app.js worked with me try it, I think it is the same syntax as yours

```
    var express = require("express");
    var mongoose = require("mongoose");
    var passport = require("passport");
    var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    var localStrategy = require("passport-local");
    var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
    var User = require("./models/user.js");
    var app = express();
    app.use(require("express-session")({
        secret: "this is a secret message",
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
    }))
    app.set("view engine", "ejs");
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })) 
    app.use(bodyParser.json())
    app.use(passport.initialize())
    app.use(passport.session())
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/auth", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});

    // passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser())
    // passport.deserializeUser(User.desrializeUser())
    passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser()); //encrypt
    passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser()); //decrypt

    app.get("/", function(req, res){
        res.render("home")
    });

    app.get("/secret", function(req, res){
        res.render("secret")
    })

    app.listen(3000, function(){
        console.log("server started!")
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Change these lines 
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser()); //encrypt
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser()); //decrypt

// With these lines
passport.serializeUser( (user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser( (user, done) =>  {
  done(null, {
    provider: user.provider,
    id: user.provider_id
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

See your directory tree very very carefully , and make sure you are importing the right file in app.js ! Also , make sure that the versions installed are these. 
It will work

[image]